# Extract the last word from a string

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, calculated-column, administration, calculated-column-formula

Is there a way to extract the last word from a string using a calculated field in SharePoint 2016?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below formula to achieve this:

```
=RIGHT([Text],LEN([Text])-FIND(" ",[Text],FIND(" ",[Text])+1))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: SharePoint formulas are tricky! Problem will be when the text have less than or more than 3 words in it OR if there are more than one space after first word in the text (data errors).